# Problem with producing A0 poster with beamer: only small part of it is displayed

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, posters

I'm working with the newest version of Beamer and am trying to produce a A0 poster from a TEX document (with Kile). The compilation to a DVI file and then to PDF (via DVItoPDF) seems to work fine. But... the produced DVI file consists of a single blank page while the PDF file apparently displays only a small, even tiny part of the poster.

I repeated the procedure with an exemplary file, downloaded from here:

http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/download/beamerposter-example.zip

But the result is the same.

Can anybody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with pdfLaTeX?

Comment: @Crowley: Yes, I did. 

The answer reads: ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps

Probably I need to apply this command with some option?

Comment: @TodorVeltchev recent tex distributions should have no problem with eps. (they will be converted to pdf automatically). Therefore i recommend to update your distro, that may solve not only the eps problem but also the initial issue.

Comment: Or if updating isn't an option, you could do `\usepackage{epstopdf}`, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063383/convert-eps-to-pdf-on-the-fly-with-pdflatex-on-the-fly

Comment: You can try to use this nice package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/a0poster or this: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/presentations/beamerposter---flow-multicolumn